# Store logs separately generated by logunsub event in a Data Extension. The Response Returned is in HTML and not in JSON format

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

[image: looks JSON but]UnsublogEvent is working as expected. the only thing is I have to pass the response back to the data extension.

```
Response = Platform.Function.InvokeExecute(lue, statusAndRequest);
```

above row gets the data in below format

```
[{"StatusCode":"Error","StatusMessage":"OnMasterUnsubscribeList","OrdinalID":0,"OrdinalIDSpecified":false,"Results":null,"ErrorCode":12012,"ErrorCodeSpecified":true}]
```

I would like to pass values separately in DE column values for ex: column Status must contain StatusCode value.

when I try to do

```
DE.Rows.Add([{ID:subkey, EmailAddress:Contact, Status:Response}])
```

it adds system.collections.arraylist to the row. I have tried multiple things but none seems to be working. any suggestions?

```
DE.Rows.Add([{ID:subkey, EmailAddress:Contact, Status:Response.Status}])
```

Generates NULL

UPDATE :
Two records for the unsublogevent which were processed. Adding the parseJSON(Response) is throwing error and not returning any value. Removing the function stringifys the Response correctly

```
    try{
    Response = Platform.Function.InvokeExecute(lue, statusAndRequest);
    var parsedResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(Response);
    Write(parsedResponse)  
    } 
  catch(e){
Write(Stringify(e));
    de1.Rows.Add([{ID:subkey, EmailAddress:id_contact, Message:e}]);}
```

Error :
{"message":"Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame.","description":"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame. - from mscorlib\r\n\r\n"}

Comment: You forgot a semicolon after   Write(parsedResponse)  - can you update and try again?

Comment: I did that but still same result, tried several other things but still same response. I am sure the response I am getting is not JSON. as soon as I put Platform.Function.ParseJSON(Response); it breaks the cloudpage (Error 500) not sure how to resolve the retrieved data into JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the ParseJSON and other functions were forcing cloudpage to break and throwing error 500. I was able to capture the values using below code

```
var statusAndRequest = [0,0];
Response = Platform.Function.InvokeExecute(lue, statusAndRequest);

var obj1 = (Response[0].StatusCode);
var obj2 = (Response[0].StatusMessage);
var obj3 = (Response[0].ErrorCode);
```

Answer (score 1):

The response you are receiving is in JSON format:

```json
[{
    "StatusCode": "Error",
    "StatusMessage": "OnMasterUnsubscribeList",
    "OrdinalID": 0,
    "OrdinalIDSpecified": false,
    "Results": null,
    "ErrorCode": 12012,
    "ErrorCodeSpecified": true
}]
```

So you will need to add one step inbetween, using `ParseJSON()` function:

```javascript
var Response = Platform.Function.InvokeExecute(lue, statusAndRequest);
var parsedResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(Response);
DE.Rows.Add([{ID:subkey, EmailAddress:Contact, Status:parsedResponse.StatusCode}])
```

Comment: I did that but somehow this is not working and still showing null when I Write(Stringify(parsedResponse)) I tried one more thing which is passing the result into another variable and then injecting into DE and it works EX: var Obj = Stringify(result) then passing it to DE and it populates the DE with the whole row. but I would like to get individual values in separate values so that it can populate relavant columns within DE

Comment: the image I have updated, is showing that the response I am getting is not in JSON format. maybe that's where the things are not right?

Comment: @pragyanshukukreti - it looks like your screenshot is showing multiple rows/records?

Comment: yes there are two records for the unsublogevent which were processed

Comment: Last suggestion - can you try: var parsedResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(Response[0]);

Comment: 500 Internal server error after above. I'll also take a break now :D